# Change LibreOffice titlebar text

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, libreoffice

The LibreOffice titlebar shows the app's name, which just adds noise. And alt-tabbing would be easier if it weren't there.

e.g. From `My foo document.xls - LibreOffice Calc` to `My foo document.xls`.

Possible? (I'm using Ubuntu.)

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I don't think this is possible. I assume you are using Windows; it might even be default OS behaviour, for example the Notepad and Chrome titles do the same thing.

Comment: @BdR No I'm on Linux/Ubuntu, i.e. Gnome. Though that's an interesting idea, if it's a Gnome thing, then maybe it can be altered with an extension or something like that.